# Vmware ESXI compatible i7 920 in a 1u?

Tags: vmware-esxi, central-processing-unit

I'm looking to build a small vm machine running vmware esxi 4.0.
Dealing with the HCL is difficult as it is, however I'm also trying to cram all of this into a 1u case if possible.

I have found a few gigabyte boards [GA-EX58-UD3R](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128375), [GA-EX58-UD4P](http://www.gigabyte.us/Products/Motherboard/Products_Overview.aspx?ProductID=2985) that would do the trick but didn't have a gpu.

I also found this supermicro board [MBD-X8STE-O](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813182167), however if I am not mistaken I would also need an io controller(onboard isn't supported?).

I'm not looking for storage in this server, I was just hoping to setup a raid 1 with two 1tb sata hard drives (not a big deal if it is significantly more cost effective to go without raid)

With any of the above mentioned motherboards it appears like I would also need a separate NIC as well [Intel Pro 1000/pt](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833106014)

From what I gather I would also need a psu in the 500watt range.

If Possible, I'd like to keep this machine around $1500.

(sorry for the lack of hyperlinks, but I don't have enough rep to post more than one)

Answer (score 3):

How about a HP DL160/165 G6 or DL320 G6, they appear to be both in your budgets and are 100% supported with ESXi.

[Clicky for link](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF04a/15351-15351-3328412-241644-3328421.html)

Comment: From what I gather the Xeon W3520 is the equivalent to the i7 920. The only difference with the 55xx is the ability for dual processors. If I were to choose a 5520 (about the same clock speed), I would already be in the $2,000 range. - Although I'm not sure if the 3520 is on the HCL list..

Comment: All models of the HP's DL range are supported by VMWare.